Use Imperial Feet & Inches inputs by default during move / edit operations?
I'm aware it's possible to use Imperial Feet & Inches measurements during edit operations by typing = before 4'2", for example.
However, is it possible to do this by default without typing the =?
Maybe, alternatively, there is an addon that makes working with imperial / CAD-style units more fluid?
Thank you!

Hi. I probably don't understand something. But, can't you just open the Scene properties tab and set the units to Imperial? Below that, choose either Feet or Inches in the Length option. I find that if I then enter simply 4'2", no =, no additional "", whether using Feet or Inches, in any or all axes, that the object moves either 4.16667ft or 50in.

This question is similar to: How to change the unit. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
